# how to export the freetext annotations with contents-richtext

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I've updated the WebViewer from a very old version to the latest version (v5.0).

And I found that there is no "contents-richtext" data in the exported XMLdata,

I've tried to set exportContentsRichText = true

but It's not effective. Does anyone know how to export the annotations with contents-richetext content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last few versions WebViewer no longer exports contents-richtext elements for newly created annotations. If an annotation has an associated contents-richtext element then WebViewer should preserve it when exporting though.

By default WebViewer doesn't take advantage of separate styles in the contents so there shouldn't be any difference with just using the contents element.

Regardless, it is still possible to export contents-richtext by extending the serialize function on annotations as shown here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pdfnet-webviewer/lptUPUcV80c/1NUgYZ_8AwAJ. Instead of adding an attribute you would create a subelement and append it as a child of the element used in the serialize function.